# Check if a submitted checkbox was checked or not in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, checked

In WooCommerce, I am trying to check if submitted checkbox is checked or not in the code below:

```
add_filter('kco_wc_api_request_args', 'krokedil_add_required_checkbox');

function krokedil_add_required_checkbox( $create ) {
    $create['options']['additional_checkbox']['text'] = 'Prenumerera på nyhetsbrevet';
    $create['options']['additional_checkbox']['checked'] = true;
    $create['options']['additional_checkbox']['required'] = false;
    return $create;
}

add_action( 'kco_wc_confirm_klarna_order', 'my_add_kco_order_data', 10, 2 );
function my_add_kco_order_data($order_id, $klarna_order ) {
    if( $klarna_order['additional_checkbox']['checked'] ) {
        add_post_meta( $order_id, 'mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed', 1 );
    } else {
        add_post_meta( $order_id, 'mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed', 0 );
    }   
}
```

But I can't get it to work. Feels like I've tried all combinations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do your checkbox have value: <input type='checkbox' value='1'>. When it is checked then passes '1' to the server.

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes are NOT sent to the PHP from the browser. You always have to check first if they exist in the array

Comment: Try `if( isset($klarna_order['additional_checkbox']) ) {`

Comment: Thank you for your replies, as you probably can tell I am new to this. I have not created the checkbox myself. It is part of a plugin I use and they told me to use that function in order to display the checkbox. I've tried to remove ```['checked']``` without success

Comment: [Enable debug](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/api/debugging/#section-1)… Then remove all code inside your 2nd function and try for testing add instead: `$checked = $klarna_order['additional_checkbox']['checked'];  error_log ( $checked, 'testing-checkbox' );`… Then on `wp-content` folder you will find a file named `debug.log`… Open it and look inside what you get submitting your checkbox checked and not checked…

Comment: Thanks for the tip Lioc! I have enabled debugging but it's not writing to the debug.log file.. The dubug.log file is not even created